# vba excel to access with certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I would like to create an access vba that imports excel data. Given that I am just starting out in vba programming I am only able to piece various codes together to make the final code. I have researched this a bit but haven't found anything that works for me. I will do my best to explain the conditions I have.

The access database should contain the vba code. It does have a couple of tables each have primary keys generated by access. The table names contain spaces so I have "01 Cutlist", "04 Panel_Data" and "08 Pallets". I need the data imported from two different workbooks meaning the first two tables get their data from one workbook while the last one will get its data from another. The data in excel are placed in the same order as the access table except for the primary key. Excel does not have a primary key column. The excel data starts at cell A7, A10 and A5 respectively. Another issue is that the column headers in excel do not always match the access table headers

I have had some success using the code from http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm. But my code keeps crashing. Following is the code I have so far

```
Sub E2A()
Dim xlx As Object, xlw As Object
Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean
blnEXCEL = False

On Error Resume Next
Set xlx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set xlx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

xTab = "Step 1 - Cutlist"
aTab = "01 Cutlist"
sCell = "A7"
oFile = "_cutlist.xlsx"
a = E2A_Loop(xlx, xlw, xTab, aTab, sCell, oFile)

xTab = "Step 4 - Panel Mass"
aTab = "04 Panel_Data"
sCell = "A10"
oFile = "_cutlist.xlsx"
a = E2A_Loop(xlx, xlw, xTab, aTab, sCell, oFile)
If blnEXCEL = True Then xlx.Quit
Set xlx = Nothing
End Sub

Function E2A_Loop(xlx, xlw, xTab, aTab, sCell, oFile)
Dim lngColumn As Long
Dim xls As Object, xlc As Object
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean
blnEXCEL = False

xlx.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xlx.Visible = False
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set xlw = xlx.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\" & Left(Application.CurrentProject.Name, 6) & oFile, , True) ' opens in read-only mode
Set xls = xlw.Worksheets(xTab)
Set xlc = xls.Range(sCell) ' this is the first cell that contains data

'Delete all records
strSQL = "Delete * From [" & aTab & "]"
dbs.Execute (strSQL)

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(aTab, dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

' write data to the recordset
Do While xlc.Value <> ""
      rst.AddNew
            For lngColumn = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 2
                rst.Fields(lngColumn + 1).Value = xlc.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value
            Next lngColumn
      rst.Update
      Set xlc = xlc.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
Set xlc = Nothing
Set xls = Nothing
xlw.Close False
Set xlw = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'crashing' - is there an error message? Step debug.

Comment: The error I get is Run-time error '3421'. Data type conversion error. I have found that the last row in the second sheet is partly empty with only its first cell having a value (blank)

Comment: You should edit question to include that info.

Comment: I am confused. First cell has what kind of value? Code already tests for empty string and should terminate when encountered.

Comment: 52 315.44 282.62 4311 1680
53 305.68 272.86 4311 1680
59 291.8 260.48 4311 1600
60 296.71 265.39 4311 1600
(blank)

Comment: I just tried to paste part of the excel data and it has not formatted correctly here, sorry. Maybe copy my previous comment to an excel sheet

Comment: Edit your question to show data there, not in comment.

Comment: I tested loop reading values from Excel. It terminates when empty cell is encountered.